# Weird JAVA date formatting giving wrong result

Tags: java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String s = "Sep 01, 2014 6:30 pm";
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm a", Locale.US);
    try{
    Date startTime = timeFormat.parse(s);
    System.out.println(startTime);
    }catch(Exception e){}
 }
}
```

The result given is Sun Dec 29 18:30:00 CST 2013, which is totally wrong

Please help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat producing wrong date time when parsing "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916958/simpledateformat-producing-wrong-date-time-when-parsing-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

`SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm a", Locale.US);`
to

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
```

As Y stands for the Week year [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value. Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different calendar year values.

More explanation on week year you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try with little y for year instead of big Y.

See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)