# SimpleDateFormat: Unparseable date MMMM yyyy

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I need to parse the string `"October 2015"` but I´m getting a `java.text.ParseException`. I've been looking for an answer but all the examples I've seen include the "day" within the string. I need to convert this string without specifying the day.

This is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");

System.out.println("La fecha despues de convertida " + format.parse(search.getFecha()));
```

And this is the exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "October 2015"
```

Comment: What format did you use? `"MMMM yyyy"` seems to work okay for me

Comment: You can use StringTokenizer class with space character as delimiter to get month and year

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Have you at least tried to read the duplicate question and its best answer? I'll give you a hint: Since you're not from an english speaking country (according to your profile) your JVM presumably uses a `Locale` which doesn't understand *"October"* and has its own word for that month. So try to tell him to use a Locale which "knows" and understands this word. The duplicate question shows you how to do that. (repost to fix a nasty typo)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to specify your date pattern,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
dateFormat.parse("October 2014");
```

Comment: It did not work for me... I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'

In Java 1.6 and prior, 'YYYY' was used to parse the **year of the week** and in further versions, it got discontinued.

EDIT: I mixed up the casing. Please ignore this answer as it is clearly not related to this problem at all.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for your claim about 'yyyy' having been used for week of the year? In [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) I see `w` used of “Week in year”.

Comment: So in Java 1.6 `yyyy` was used for "year of the week" even if the source code suggests something else and in 1.7 `YYYY` replaced it, because this is now "year of the week"? interesting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739514/simpledateformatdd-mmm-yyyy-printing-year-one-year-ahead?lq=1

I mixed up the case, sorry.