# Date to String and String to Date Error Java

Tags: java, string, date

I am changing my date to String and again from string to date but the date after converting from string to date is different than before .See the Code

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DateChange {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);

    Date currentDate = null;
    try {

        currentDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        System.out.println(date + " \n" + currentDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Here if date object has value Mon Sep 04 12:51:33 IST 2017

Than currentDate has          Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017

I know something is wrong with the code and I am unable to figure it out.So please point it out for me.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Java is that? If Java 8 or more, consider using the new datetime API

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: Related: [SimpleDateFormat producing wrong date time when parsing “YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916958/simpledateformat-producing-wrong-date-time-when-parsing-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm)

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you scrap the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Lots of people have experienced lots of problems with them, your is just one in a seemingly neverending row. Today we have so much better in [the modern Java date & time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a wrong format. By checking [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can see that

- `d`: day in month
- `M`: month in year
- `Y`: week year
- `y`: year

So the correct format would be: `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: Thanks. This silly mistake took my 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your format `String` is incorrect. You've used `YYYY`, but you need `yyyy`. Like,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```